# Jetpack Compose Observe mutableStateOf in ViewModel

Tags: viewmodel, android-jetpack-compose

I have a need to update the user profile switch

1. ViewModel

```kotlin
class ProfileViewModel : BaseViewModel() {

    var greet = mutableStateOf(user.pushSetting.greet)
    var message = mutableStateOf(user.pushSetting.message)
    var messageDetails = mutableStateOf(user.pushSetting.messageDetails)

    var follow = mutableStateOf(user.pushSetting)
    var like = mutableStateOf(user.pushSetting.like)
    var comment = mutableStateOf(user.pushSetting.comment)

    fun updateUser() {
        println("--")
    }
}
```

2.Composable

```kotlin
@Composable
fun SettingCard(viewModel: ProfileViewModel) {

    Lists {
        Section {
            TextRow(text = "手机号码") { }
            TextRow(text = "修改密码", line = false) { }
        }

        Section {
            SwitchRow(text = "新好友通知", checkedState = viewModel.greet)
            SwitchRow(text = "新消息通知", checkedState = viewModel.message)
            SwitchRow(text = "消息显示详细", line = false, checkedState = viewModel.messageDetails)
        }
    }
}
```

3.SwitchRow

```kotlin
@Composable
fun SwitchRow(text: String, line: Boolean = true, checkedState: MutableState<Boolean>) {

    ListItem(
        text = { Text(text) },
        trailing = {
            Switch(
                checked = checkedState.value,
                onCheckedChange = { checkedState.value = it },
                colors = SwitchDefaults.colors(checkedThumbColor = MaterialTheme.colors.primary)
            )
        }
    )
}
```

How can I observe the change of the switch and call updateUser() in ViewModel

I know this is a way, but it is not ideal. The network update will be called every time it is initialized. Is there a better solution?

```kotlin
LaunchedEffect(viewModel.greet) {
     viewModel.updateUser()
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The best solution for this would be to have [unidirectional flow](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-state#2) with `SwitchRow` with a lambda as @Codecameo advised.

But if you want to observe a MutableState inside your `Viewmodel` you can use `snapshotFlow`s  as

```
var greet: MutableState<Boolean> = mutableStateOf(user.pushSetting.greet)

init {
    snapshotFlow { greet.value }
        .onEach {
            updateUser()
        }
        .launchIn(viewModelScope)
        //...
}
```

> Create a Flow from observable Snapshot state. (e.g. state holders
> returned by mutableStateOf.) snapshotFlow creates a Flow that runs
> block when collected and emits the result, recording any snapshot
> state that was accessed. While collection continues, if a new Snapshot
> is applied that changes state accessed by block, the flow will run
> block again, re-recording the snapshot state that was accessed. If the
> result of block is not equal to the previous result, the flow will
> emit that new result. (This behavior is similar to that of
> Flow.distinctUntilChanged.) Collection will continue indefinitely
> unless it is explicitly cancelled or limited by the use of other Flow
> operators.

Comment: Observation in ViewModel is the best way to deal with it. snapshotFlow observation is effective. I read the document and there are more usages. Thanks for sharing. I marked the answer.

Comment: How does this actually work? Google's docs are appalling. How can a MutableState possibly know how to subscribe a SnapshotFlow to future changes when the only interaction the SnapshotFlow has with it is to read its value in a lambda? Does this mean that reading a MutableState's value has side-effects so I should never try to do so except in a Composable or SnapshotFlow or similar?

Comment: The snapshot is just a flow. If you don't add distinctUntilChanged to it, it won't provide it to you.

Comment: `launchIn` doesn't work for SnapshotFlow

Comment: it seems it's better to always use `StateFlow` inside `ViewModel`, especially if you need to verify if input fields are filled with the new data or previously submitted data (saved in database/datastore) and disable e.g. "update profile" button if data is the same (no need to do the request with the same data), you can't use functions like `combine` with `State`, so that's always better to use `StateFlow`

Comment: or we can do something like this: `val isNewData = combine(prevDataStateFlow, snapshotFlow { firstNameTextField.text }, snapshotFlow { lastNameTextField.text }) { prevData, firstName, lastName -> ... your logic }.stateIn(viewModelScope, SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(), false)`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a `mutableStateListOf`

For example:

```
val items = mutableStateListOf("A", "B", "C")
```

then use

```
init {
    snapshotFlow { items.toList() }
        .onEach {
            doSomething()
        }
        .launchIn(viewModelScope)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a callback lamba in `SwitchRow` and call it upon any state change

```
@Composable
fun SettingCard(viewModel: ProfileViewModel) {
Lists {
    Section {
        TextRow(text = "手机号码") { }
        TextRow(text = "修改密码", line = false) { }
    }

    Section {
        SwitchRow(text = "新好友通知", checkedState = viewModel.greet) {
            viewModel.updateUser()
        }
        SwitchRow(text = "新消息通知", checkedState = viewModel.message) {
            viewModel.updateUser()
        }
        SwitchRow(text = "消息显示详细", line = false, checkedState = viewModel.messageDetails) {
            viewModel.updateUser()
        }
    }
}
}

@Composable
   fun SwitchRow(
   text: String,
   line: Boolean = true,
   checkedState: MutableState<Boolean>,
   onChange: (Boolean) -> Unit
) {
ListItem(
    text = { Text(text) },
    trailing = {
        Switch(
            checked = checkedState.value,
            onCheckedChange = {
                onChange(it)
                checkedState.value = it
            },
            colors = SwitchDefaults.colors(checkedThumbColor = MaterialTheme.colors.primary)
        )
    }
)
}
```

**Another approach:**

You can keep `MutableStateFlow<T>` in your viewmodel and start observing it in `init` method and send a value to it from `SwitchRow`, like viewModel.stateFlow.value = value.
Remember, `MutableStateFlow` will only trigger in the value changes. If you set same value twice it will discard second value and will execute for first one.

```
val stateFlow = MutableStateFlow<Boolean?>(null)

init {
    stateFlow
        .filterNotNull()
        .onEach { updateUser() }
        .launchIn(viewModelScope)
}
```

In switchRow

```
viewmodel.stateFlow.value = !(viewmodel.stateFlow.value?: false)
```

This could be one potential solution. You can implement it in your convenient way.

Comment: This is the easiest way, although there is a lot of redundant code. Still looking forward to a better observation method

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Your second method is valid, similar to @Thracian ’s answer. For the best answer, I marked Thracian. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

We can combine StateFlows and States like this in ViewModel, for example to observe all states and do some logic:

```
val isNewData = combine(
    previouslySentDataStateFlow, // StateFlow
    snapshotFlow { firstNameTextFieldValue.text }, // by mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue())
    snapshotFlow { lastNameTextFieldValue.text }
) { prevData, firstName, lastName ->
    prevData?.firstName != firstName || prevData.lastName != lastName 
}.stateIn(viewModelScope, SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(), false)
```