# Manually observe SnapshotStateList

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

How to manually observe SnapshotStateList or MutableState? It said that mutableStateListOf returns list that can be observed, but I can't find such method. Is it true that only Compose can observe changes?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jetpack Compose Observe mutableStateOf in ViewModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69230831/jetpack-compose-observe-mutablestateof-in-viewmodel)

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to observe of a state object, such as the result of `mutableStateOf` or `mutableStateListOf()`, is by using `snapshotFlow`.

`snapshotFlow`'s `block` parameter will be called when any state object it uses has been changed and the result of `block` will be emitted to the flow such as `snapshotFlow { snapshotList.toList() }`. Note the `toList()` is required here otherwise the `snapshotList` itself is used which the `snapshotFlow` doesn't consider changed (it is always the same instance) so it will only emit once. In compose runtime version 1.4, `toList()` was changed so that calling `toList()` on a `SnapshotStateList` does not perform a copy.

Alternately, you can use `SnapshotStateObserver` which enables multiplexing a single apply observer to observe a multitude of lambdas. This is what Compose UI layout and draw use, for example, to track when to recalculate the layout and when to replay drawing commands.

State objects do not have an `observe` or `subscribe` equivalent because `Snapshots` was designed and optimized to observe an open, dynamic set of objects read by a function and any function it calls (such as Compose needs); and no fast path for a single object (which Compose does not need)  was implemented and is therefore expensive. Having an `observe` method of a state object would imply it is fast and cheap, which it is not.

Comment: `snapshotFlow` is a poor vehicle for observing changes to SnapshotStateList, because, unlike this answer suggests, the result of `block' is emitted only when non-equal to the prior result, which for SnapshotStateList is never the case, it's the same object.

Comment: You have to resort to nonsense like `snapshotFlow { doSomething(list) }.collect()` to make it work. `snapshotFlow` really looks misconceived from this perspective, there is no reason to combine state updates and equality.

Comment: Adam Powell just laid things out to me on this topic in the Kotlin Compose Slack. Processing the list in the snapshotFlow block is safe and essentially the recommended solution, or making a list copy to pass down.

Comment: I never implied or stated that the result of `block` is emitted differently for `snapshotFlow` when you return a `SnapshotSteteList` than any other result of `block`.

Comment: The way the answer is written leads readers to shoot themselves in the foot when using `SnapshotStateList`. `snapshotFlow { snapshotStateList }` does not work, it needs to be something like `snapshotFlow { snapshotStateList.toList() }` or `snapshotFlow { doSomething(list) }`. This problem does not exist for (Mutable)State, because here the commonly observed element is not the state object itself, but its `value` property. In the case of `SnapshotStateList` the commonly observed element is the state object itself. Easy to say in theory but in actual use this tends to cause plentiful bugs.

Comment: `snapshotFlow { snapshotStateList }` only ever emits once, because the list object itself never changes. By contrast, `snapshotFlow { state.value }` or `snapshotFlow { delegatedStateValue }` emits as expected.

Comment: In 1.4 I added a `toList()` implementation to `SnapshotStateList` to address this. If the expression is changed to `snapshotFlow { snapshotStateList.toList() }`, this will will give you the results you expect efficiently.  Using `toList()` works before 1.4 but calls the default `toList()` implementation which makes a copy of the list. In 1.4 this returns the underlying immutable list without a copy.

Comment: That will be very helpful, thank you @chuckj! I guess you could close my issue then: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/233587517