# How to trigger LaunchedEffect when mutableStateList is changed?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, jetbrains-compose, compose-multiplatform

In Jetpack/Desktop Compose I want a coroutine to run in response to changes to a `SnapshotStateList`.

In this example:

```kotlin
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.material.Button
import androidx.compose.material.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.LaunchedEffect
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateListOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember

@Composable
fun TestMutableList() {
    val list = remember { mutableStateListOf(1, 2, 3) }

    LaunchedEffect(list) {
        println("List was changed.")
    }

    Column {
        Button(onClick = { list[0] = 0 }) {
            Text("Change List")
        }
        list.forEach { Text(it.toString()) }
    }
}
```

the `LaunchedEffect` was run on the first composition. And the `Composable` recomposes when I click the button, so it knows that the `SnapshotStateList<Int>` changed. However, it was not run when clicking the button. I understand that this is because the `key` is the reference to the `SnapshotStateList<Int>` and that did not change.

How can I have the `LaunchedEffect` run every time that the list is modified?

Comment: You want to look at snapshotFlow, but again pay attention to the fact that the list object itself never changes, so don't return that from the snapshotFlow directly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70404434

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With convert SnapshotStateList to ImmutableList, you can achieve to aim.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun TestMutableList() {
    val list = remember { mutableStateListOf(1, 2, 3) }

    LaunchedEffect(list.toList()) {
        println("List was changed.")
    }

    Column {
        Button(onClick = { list[0] = 0 }) {
            Text("Change List")
        }
        list.forEach { Text(it.toString()) }
    }
}
```

Comment: i don't know where you got this stuff but works man, thank you, can you share the reference link where got to know __.toList()__ works

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and got it working using the list size instead of the list itself.

Like this:

```
val list = remember { mutableStateListOf(1, 2, 3) }

LaunchedEffect(list.size) {
    println("List was changed.")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can update an integer for anytime you change list so it will trigger when that value is changed

```
val list = remember { mutableStateListOf(1, 2, 3) }

var changeIndex by remember {
    mutableStateOf(0)
}

LaunchedEffect(list.size, changeIndex) {
    // add an if here if you don't want to trigger when changeIndex is 0
    println("List was changed.")
}

Column {
    Button(onClick = { list[0] = 0 }) {
        changeIndex ++
        Text("Change List")
    }
    list.forEach { Text(it.toString()) }
}
```