# How do Composables get notified to recompose when a MutableState changes?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I don't understand how the Compose system "knows" that it needs to recompose certain composables when MutableStates that they're observing change value. For example, AIUI, I could write something like:

```kotlin
class StateHolder {
    val theState by mutableStateOf("The state")
}

...

@Composable
fun StateDisplay(stateHolder: StateHolder) {
    Text(stateHolder.theState)
}
```

Then, elsewhere in my code I can assign a new value to `theState`, and that will trigger a recomposition and the display will be updated to show the new value. (At the moment I'm not sure whether that means `StateDisplay()` gets run again, or just its `Text` child).

My question is, how on earth does a `MutableState` know what's observing it, and what it needs to do to update the observer? From the above code it looks like the `MutableState` can only know that something called its getter, but not know what called it, and the composables can only know that they called a getter, but not know when they need to call it again.

Similarly, I wondered if it was possible to observe a `MutableState` from elsewhere. It's probably not a conventional pattern in Android/Compose because all I could find on the subject was [this answer about snapshotFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69235908/1541150). But again, how does the flow know when a new value needs to be emitted when it looks like the only relationship that's been established between the flow and state is that one called the other's getter?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, Compose only recompose components that are actually consuming this data, as an example imagine you have a Parent component like:

```kotlin
class MyViewModel : ViewModel(){
    private val _myObservableStringInViewModel: MutableStateFlow<String> = MutableStateFlow("Hello World")
    val myObservableStringInViewModel: StateFlow = _myObservableStringInViewModel.asStateFlow()
}

@Composable
fun ParentComponent(viewModel: MyViewModel){
    val myObservedString by viewModel.myObservableStringInViewModel.collectAsState()
    Scaffold{
        MyChildComponent(data = myObservedString)
    }
}

@Composable
fun MyChildComponent(data: String){
    Text(text = data)
}
```

In this case `MyChildComponent` it's the only one that is going to be affected by recomposition, because compose only recompose those components that are actually using the data, also works the same with `Text()` components, imagine you have 3 observables `MutableStateFlow`, and 3 `Text()` components being feed by those respective, if one of those change, only the `Text()` component that is being feed by this particular `MutableStateFlow` is the only one that is going to be re-composed.

And according to your second question, this example shows the most used approach to implement `StateFlow` in Compose, also you must use an activity or fragment between your `ViewModel` and the composable, but there are many approaches to do this, so I'll leave this to your particular research, also you can use Compose `ViewModel` direct injection but this is in beta for now.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. I know Compose only recomposes components that read the state, but how does Compose know when the state has been updated? In most languages it isn't possible for a lambda to connect itself as an observer of a state simply by calling the state's getter like that. Something else has to be establishing that connection behind the scenes.

Comment: That's what StateFlow and MutableStateFlow are for, just like flow, when their data is being collected, it starts streaming directly to collector in a background thread, and since ".collectAsState()" is a bind overriden function of composable that basically collects the streamed data as an observer, is internally prepared to trigger recomposition when data has changed it's Internal instance ID.

Comment: But like I said, in order to trigger a listener for you stateFlow, you should collect it inside composable first, something like, `val myState by stateHolder.theState.collectAsState()` <---- This is the observer, an stateFlow should never be called directly from composables because this is only going to take the first value (default), but no changes are going to be listened